# Number of trees generates from DFS

Tags: algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph, let $a,b \in V$. The number of trees in the forests returned by DFS(a) and DFS(b) is the same.

I thing its true but have no idea how to write it.
any suggestions ?

Comment: rooted trees? unrooted trees?

Comment: https://math.mit.edu/~djk/18.310/18.310F04/counting_trees.html

Comment: There is nothing related to the algorithem in the link. and rooted trees

Comment: please, may you elaborate on your question? What does DFS(a) and DFS(b) mean? how does your version of DFS work? DFS in principle returns a forest where the number of trees equals the number of connected components. I do not understand your question very well

Comment: "DFS in principle returns a forest where the number of trees equals the number of connected components" this is exactly what I need to prove. but I do'nt know how.

Comment: I believe there is a proof here https://www.amazon.com.br/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844